# Is it possible to use the Distributed Object Events for Hazelcast Client?

Tags: hazelcast

As stated in Docs: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Events/Event_Listeners_for_Clients.html

Client does not supports the Distributed Object Events. Is there any way to detect the Events for a given Map on server and Refresh the delta using the Client Instance. I have Centralized HZ Distributed Cache. Each time something changes on server side; I want the client notification to fecth the changes/delta.

Client supports http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Events/Cluster_Events/Listening_for_Distributed_Object_Events.html

I want to know if it can Supports MAp/Distributed Map events
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Events/Distributed_Object_Events/Listening_for_Map_Events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MapListeners` on client side, there are several types of events you can observe:

- `EntryAddedListener`
- `EntryRemovedListener`
- `EntryUpdatedListener`
- `MapClearedListener`
- `EntryEvictedListener`
- ...

Look into [MapListener JavaDoc](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/listener/MapListener.html) for more details.

Usage is simple:

```java
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
client.getMap("test").addEntryListener(new EntryAddedListener<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public void entryAdded(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
        System.out.println("Added: " + event.getKey() + "=" + event.getValue());
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: So if the Item got added by remote node on cluster farm; the client will get notified ? Or it is event notification for Local add operation for that client? Seems to be confusing to me based on documentation. I will try to run some sample PoC and Check.